# How to create a simple draggable marker in OpenLayers

Tags: maps, openlayers

Very simple question, how can I create a draggable marker in an OpenLayers map, and get the latlon when its been dragged. From google, it seems that you can have draggable vectors, but not draggable markers.

I've seen some references to `OpenLayers.Control.DragMarker`, but this doesn't seem to be in the "core" library. It's used in [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/tschaub/feature/examples/drag-marker.html) example but that seems to be using a custom OpenLayers JS file, so I have no idea how to go about including that in my code.

Code thus far (to add a simple marker):

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS The Layer","",
    {  url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.', alpha: true,
        type: 'png', getURL: overlay_getTileURL 
    });

map.addLayers([layer]);


    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -100 ,100 );
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done that, but I can't find that code now. Take a look at this OpenLayers Example:

[Drag Feature](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I can work with something like that, I'll give it a go

Comment: Great, try it out and decide which answer that deserves the "solution" mark. ;-)

Comment: Yep, and using "features" as used in this example is indeed the correct way to do this. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the markers with features? look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884692/dragging-markers-with-ordnance-survey-openlayers-api)

Comment: I'd rather stick with simple markers if possible, unless this isn't supported

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with that a bit, until I dag into the documentation and realized that in 2022 it is very easy to do that:

```
const translate = new Translate({
   features: new Collection([feature]),
})

translate.on('translateend', e => {
   let lonLat = toLonLat(e.coordinate)
})

map.addInteraction(translate)
```